# Strange Virtuemart error message: COM_VIRTUEMART_MIGRATION_WARN_VM1_EXTENSIONS

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I am getting this error when trying to get to the virtuemart admin page:
COM_VIRTUEMART_MIGRATION_WARN_VM1_EXTENSIONS

I am using Joomla 2.5 with virtuemart 2.0

I cannot identify the exact moment when this problem appeared.

This is the source code that's generating the error message:

```
if (!class_exists( 'VmConfig' )) 
    require(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR.DS.'components'.DS.'com_virtuemart'.DS.'helpers'.DS.'config.php');

VmConfig::loadConfig();

$attentionText = JText::_('COM_VIRTUEMART_MIGRATION_WARN_VM1_EXTENSIONS');

vmWarn($attentionText);

echo $attentionText;

vmTrace('Called by',TRUE);
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing is an untranslated language string. I've just had a look at the language file and the error that is supposed to show is:

**Attention: You have still old vm extensions in your joomla installation active, uninstall or disable them**

Simple ensure you have the most up to date version of all VirtueMart related extensions whether it be a component, plugin or module.

Hope this helps